# How does a two-stage supercharger work?

Tags: piston-engine

How does a two-stage [supercharger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Merlin#Supercharger) like the one found in a Rolls-Royce Merlin work? Does the pilot have any control over it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually yes.  A two stage supercharger used a compressor with two or more compression stages, often with an inter cooler between them, driven by a transmission with different gear ratios to control the compressor speed.  A schematic of this type of supercharger can be seen here on a Rolls Royce Eagle engine.

[image]

[image: Illustration by Flight International]

On the Supermarine Spitfires powered by the larger Griffon engines the supercharger speed had both a LO and HIGH setting and could either be manually controlled by the pilot or automatically controlled.  The HIGH setting was not recommended at lower altitudes to prevent overboosting during operations there.